# How to set up authentication already setup in MEAN app in Ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, ionic-framework, mean-stack

I am developing an application using MEAN Stack. However I am developing an app using ionic framework for the same application. How would I use the same authentication used in MEAN, in Ionic framework app?

Answer (score 1):

Ionic Framework is built on top of Angular. I would suggest you to use token-based authentications for that; one popular strategy would be JSON Web Tokens (JWT). JWT is basically a standard to transmit data between communicating entities (client/server) through JSON.

I am not exactly sure what kind of authentication system are you using in your MEAN app. It's very likely that you will be using cookie-based authentication. If that is the case, you will need to alter your code so that instead of storing user/session info in cookies, you'll store them in JSON. You can check out the `jsonwebtoken` module for that.

There are a couple of token based authentication tutorials out there. You could try these out:

- https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact I am using cookie-based authentication. Any other work around for this other than JWT?